# filling an excel sheet with data asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, openxml

I am writing a routine to create and fill an Excel sheet in `ASP.NET MVC`. The object that I want to transfer to the sheet is a List, where T is a structure.

Do you know of any piece of code that does this?

The constructor that do this is:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
… 
 public byte[] ExcelContent;

 public ExportExcel(List<OrdViewModel> ol)
        {
            MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream();

            SpreadsheetDocument XlsxDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memstream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

            WorkbookPart workbookpart = XlsxDoc.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.  
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

            // Add Sheets to the Workbook.  
            Sheets sheets = XlsxDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
                AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

            Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
            {
                Id = XlsxDoc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                SheetId = 1,
                Name = "Sheet1"
            };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            // code here…

            XlsxDoc.Close();

            ExcelContent = memstream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? Does this code not work for you? Does it throw an error? Does it not give you the desired output?

Comment: This code was taken from a site. Where I say `// code here…` is where I want to insert the code to fill the excel document. In this moment, I have no code where is the above tag...

Comment: So write it yourself? Stack Overflow isn't here to do that for you, we're here to assist with problems with code you've written.

Comment: Problem solved (almost…) in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825738/exporting-data-to-excel-format-error-when-opening-resulting-file

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [SwiftExcel](https://github.com/RomanPavelko/SwiftExcel) library. It was designed to maximize performance and minimize memory usage when writing to `Excel`:

```
public ExportExcel(List<OrdViewModel> ol)
{
    using (var ew = new ExcelWriter("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx"))
    {
        for (var row = 1; row <= ol.Count; row++)
        {
            var item = ol[row-1];
            ew.Write(item.YourProperty1, 1, row);
            ew.Write(item.YourProperty2, 2, row);
            ew.Write(item.YourProperty3, 3, row);
            ew.Write(item.YourProperty4, 4, row);
        }
    }
}
```